# How to create Custom Module in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I want to create own custom module for angular js
Any one please tell me.
I searched many times in internet.
But i found same result like below

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
```

But don't want like this

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have an app that you created with the Angular CLI, create a module using the CLI by entering the following command in the root project directory. Replace ModuleName with the name of your module:

**ng generate module ModuleName**

Answer (score 0):

For Angular js I think You need to add one module.js file and write your module like below:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('FacebookIntegrationModule', [
         'ngMaterial',
        'ngAnimate'
        ])
    .config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
                
    }])
})();
```

In your main module add your custom module in my case app.module.js added as below

```
var app = angular.module('my.App', ['FacebookIntegrationModule'
])
```